# filter array based upon categories

Tags: javascript

there is a an array of markers, each marker belongs to one or more categories.

how would you implement a search/filter to retrieve all markers having cat = X ?

for example:

- all markers with cat = 9 ?
- all markers with cat = 5 and 9 ?

```
Gmaps.map.markers = [
    {"id":9,"cat":"3, 5, 6","lat":"52.50","lng":"13.32"},
    {"id":11,"cat":"3","lat":"52.51","lng":"13.44"},
    {"id":12,"cat":"1, 2, 5","lat":"47.89","lng":"10.62"},
    {"id":13,"cat":"1, 2, 3, 4, 5","lat":"47.77","lng":"10.61"},
    {"id":15,"cat":"1, 6","lat":"40.60","lng":"-73.44"},
    {"id":16,"cat":"1, 3, 5, 9","lat":"51.89","lng":"17.16"},
    {"id":17,"cat":"9","lat":"52.37","lng":"9.73"}
];
```

Comment: I notice there is a comma separated list of cat ids within your structure. An array may make if easier to do an exacting search without resorting to using regex.

Comment: Have you tried [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)?

Comment: @dqhendricks: You could just `split` the string on `', '`.

Comment: @Rocket Very true. Although probably still not optimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modified it to find the cat 4 as well...

```
function findMarkersContaining ( markers, needleArray ) {
  var matches = [];
  var markerLength = markers.length;
  var needleArrayLength = needleArray.length;
    for ( var i = 0; i < markerLength; i++ ) {
      for ( var e = 0; e < needleArrayLength; e++ ) {
        var singleNeedle = needleArray[e];
        if ( $.inArray( singleNeedle, markers[i].cat.split(",")) !== -1 ) {
           matches.push( markers[i] );
        }
      }
    }
  return matches;
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this that uses regex to find whether something in the needleArray is found within the cat comma separated list, and if so, add that marker to the returned array.

```
function findMarkersContaining ( markers, needleArray ) {
   var matches = [];
   var markerLength = markers.length;
   var needleArrayLength = needleArray.length;
   for ( var i = 0; i < markerLength; i++ ) {
      for ( var e = 0; e < needleArrayLength; e++ ) {
         var regex = new RegExp( '(^| )' + needleArray[e] + '(,|$)' );
         if ( markers[i].cat.search( regex ) !== -1 ) {
            matches.push( markers[i] );
         }
      }
   }
   return matches;
}
```

Comment: @3raindrops Which is exactly what you wanted right? Those records all contain cat with a value of "1" in the comma separated list.

Comment: @3raindrops I am just now noticing however that your second case requires that both cat ids be present, the function I wrote returns the result if either of the cat ids are present (basically cat = 5 **or** 9 instead of cat = 5 **and** 9). The code should not be hard to modify to do what you are asking however.

Comment: yeah, cat X AND Y and Z  ... would be ideal, thats what i'm aiming for! but for now i modified it to find the cat 4 as well...

Comment: basically i am trying to simplify the code for displaying markers on a gmap, these markers belonging to various categories at the same time, and i have to admit i am still in the process of thinking of which way to go... one example would be: [link](http://events.modabot.com) i would like to find another approach though, just for the sake of it ;-)

Comment: Thank you for pushing me in the right direction!
i managed to find a crisp and clear solution for my gmaps multiple marker categories problem. if you are interested in the code i could pass it on to you.